# When I use "npm run buid" with Vite, "import.meta.env." is replaced by {} in dist

Tags: github, environment-variables, vite, production, secret-key

I need to use a secret key for a fetch to an API. I work with Vite. I want to have my key available in development environment so I created a file env.development.local with my key :

```
VITE_KEY=myKey
```

and it works just fine in development : import.meta.env.VITE_KEY is replaced by myKey and I'm able to use it.

I didn't create a file env.production because I don't want to display my key publicly on gitHub, and so I don't want it to be in my Javascript file in the dist directory.

And I would like to declare an environment variable for production on Vercel or a secret action on github, with my  VITE_KEY inside of it. But that doesn't work. And I noticed than when I run "npm run build" to bundle my files for distribution, import.meta.env.VITE_KEY is replaced by {}.VITE_KEY. Is that normal?

How can I do to declare and use this environment variable in production with an external service like vercel or github? I searched for hours but I can't find any answer for this problem...

Comment: I have not deployed to Vercel before *(and you did not add details of your configurations or error screenshots)* but the variable is being replaced by `{}.VITE_KEY` most likely because the variable was not found during the build process. I'll add an answer to share how you can typically configure environment variables to work both locally and in production, without exposing your values.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, the variable is being replaced by `{}.VITE_KEY` because **the variable was not found during your `npm run build` process**

i.e you only defined it for the development environment - `.env.local`.

**What you can do:**

1. use `.env` to take care of both local and production environments, or
2. add a `.env.production` file **but ensure you add it to `.gitignore` file** so it does not get pushed to GitHub.

**i.e your `.gitginore` file should include this:**

```
#Ignore .env files
.env
.env.local
.env.production
```

That way, the `.env.production` file is also ignored.

As for Vercel, you also did not add enough details to debug, but ensure you are setting an environment variable for `VITE_KEY` in the deploy settings for the project.

I personally use Netlify and these work for React + Vite projects, but Vercel may have other settings, so check out [this](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables) guide for more details.

One of these should resolve the issue, **otherwise, you need to improve your questions with further details.**